# Disord js bot user-info issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to create a bot, and one of its commands is `user-info`

for eg. `!user-info @<username>`

and i want it to display username, id and the avatar
like:

```
username:<username>
Id:<User Id>
Avatar:<the avatar >
```

Below is the code i used:

```
else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}user-info`)) {
        var member = message.mentions.users.first();
        message.channel.send(`Username: ${member.username}\n ID:${member.id}\n Avatar:${member.displayAvatarURL()}` );

    }
```

However it doesn't work, when i remove the avatar part the output comes out as :

```
Username:undefined
Id:<the id>
```

When I add the avatar part I just get a huge error on the command module when I use the bot command. What's the right way and what did I get wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use an Embed for this, as those can display images in a better way, the code for your request would be:

```
var user = message.mentions.users.first();
message.channel.send({
    embed: {
        title: `Profile of ${user.tag}`,
        thumbnail: {
            url: user.displayAvatarURL(),
        },
        fields: [
            {
                title: "ID:",
                value: user.id
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

You can find more on this [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do have a question though. What's the difference between "user.tag" and "user.username"?

Comment: username is the user's username. (For example AtulRy). The user's tag is the user's username and the discriminator. (For example AtulRy#1234)

Comment: @AtulRy What Jakye said. Both can be used, that is just personal preference. Did this solve your problem? If yes, make sure to mark it as solution, so it's easier for other users to find :)